# Magento2 How to get PHPSESSID value of Guest User?

Tags: magento2, session, cookie

Magento2 How can I get PHPSESSID value for Guest User?

I need to use it to identify frontend user in PWA, using the rest API

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rest API the on load of page you have to run the guest authentication request and sace in local storage. Later when customer is logged in you need to replace with customer auth hash.